# Unwanted behaviour of siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[ \frac{x}{\SI{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Question**

Why is the `per-mode` option set to `symbol`? Shouldn't it be `fraction` or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the difference bettween `per-mode=fraction` and `per-mode=symbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[ \frac{x}{\SI[per-mode=fraction]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\[ \frac{x}{\SI[per-mode=symbol]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\[ \textstyle \frac{x}{\SI[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\[ \displaystyle \frac{x}{\SI[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\[ \frac{x}{\SI[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\[ \frac{x}{\displaystyle\SI[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{4}{\m\per\degree}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, in the last two equations, `\per` should be printed as `fraction`, like the [`siunitx` manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (bottom of p. 41) points out:

> Setting per-mode to symbol-or-fraction will use the symbol setting for
>   in line math, and the fraction setting when used in `\displaystyle`
>   math.

There is probably a bug or an omission of some option.

Comment: How is it a bug? The denominator of a `displaystyle` fraction is in `textstyle` by default, just see the output of `\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}`.

Comment: @T.Verron Okay. I, as well, thought it was in `\displaystyle` math.

Comment: I'd say this is a subtly that should probably go into the manual: @T.Verron is correct that `\textstyle` is active at the point of choice (and I'd say this looks 'best'), but that might not be obvious to most people.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the `\displaystyle` in the denominator. As expected the visual result is not the same as using the `per-mode=fraction`.